# InfluxDB get maximum value of moving average

Tags: max, influxdb, moving-average

To get the moving average of a series in InfluxDB you can do the following:

```
SELECT MOVING_AVERAGE(<field_key>,<window>) FROM <measurement_name>
```

(from the [influxdb documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/functions/#moving-average))

That will return a dataset with the moving average on each point.
However I would like to get only the maximum of that dataset.

Of course I could do that in my script but then I would have to download all the data of the moving average first, and then process it locally. (My InfluxDB server is not on the local network)

Is there a way to get *only* the maximum of the moving average without getting the complete moving average data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nate Good who pointed me towards subqueries I ended up with the following solution:

```
SELECT MAX(moving_average) FROM (SELECT MOVING_AVERAGE(<field_key>,<window>) FROM <measurement_name>)
```

That will give you a max value and the time it occured. For my own case (using the python client) it gave me this result:

```
ResultSet({'('power', None)': [{'max': 17147.76, 'time': '2016-08-19T19:18:48Z'}]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.2 was recently released with support for subqueries
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#subqueries

That would be one way to solve your problem.  You could probably also do a GROUP BY using a large time interval.  And as I look at the docs they even show that:

The MOVING_AVERAGE() query with a nested function and a GROUP BY time() clause:

`SELECT MOVING_AVERAGE(<function>(<field_key>),<window>) FROM <measurement_name> WHERE <stuff> GROUP BY time(<time_interval>)`

Comment: The subquery looks good, I wil check that. If I understood the nested function with group by correctly, then that won't help since the nested function is executed first but I need the moving average first